# Azure AD B2C extension attributes in Relying Party Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have 4 applications using Azure AD B2C custom SignIn/SignUp policies. Each Application has their own custom attributes, but use same IDP and Azure AD Configurations. Currently each application maintain their own set of Base, Extension and RP files and all are working fine.

We are in the process of achieving a common Base and Extension file that can be used across all applications and implement application specific RelyingParty file including extension attributes.

When we move all the extension attribute declarations and definitions to the SignUpSignIn Policy, we are getting this error while uploading the policy

```
Unable to upload policy. Reason : Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_XXXXXX" of tenant "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com".Persisted claims for technical profile "AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" in policy "B2C_1A_XXXXX" of tenant "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com" must have one of the following claims: logonIdentifier.userName, logonIdentifier.emailAddress, userPrincipalName.
```

When I add

```
    <"PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName">
```

to

```
    "TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail",
```

I am able to upload the policy, and on signUp as soon as I click Register, User is getting created in the AD, but the UI shows error message "You are already registered, please press the back button and sign in instead." and does not navigate away from the signup page.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Any thoughts on this Please

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your policies are creating a `userPrincipalName` that is already in the directory. Usually, in the starter packs, `userPrincipalName` is not sent in the profile `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail`. Instead, `signInNames.emailAddress` or `signInNames.userName` is sent to the directory. (`logonIdentifier.userName` and `logonIdentifier.emailAddress` are typos in the error message and should be fixed soon.)

If `userPrincipalName` is your intended claim to be written to the directory, then your best bet is to [collect Application Insights logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom), and then see what is being sent to the directory for user creation. Then you can validate whether those are the right values for the user account that is signing up.

If needed, you can the send a request directly to Azure AD Graph API with those values and see if the behavior is as expected.